# Center a div in HTML

Tags: html

I need to put two textarea inline and center both of them. However, I cannot find a way to center them after making them side by side. Is there anyway I can do it?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    .inline-div {
      display: inline-block;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="inline-div">
    <p align="center">Input:</p>
    <textarea id="display_new_language"></textarea>
  </div>
  <div class="inline-div">
    <p align="center">Information:</p>
    <textarea id="display"></textarea>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add Parent **DIV** to both inline elements and give css **text-align:center** as shown below:

```css
.inline-div {
  display: inline-block;
}

.center-div {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="center-div">
  <div class="inline-div">
    <p align="center">Input:</p>
    <textarea id="display_new_language"></textarea>
  </div>
  <div class="inline-div">
    <p align="center">Information:</p>
    <textarea id="display"></textarea>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you!! This works perfectly in my code. I always thought that text-align can only apply to text.

Answer (score 1):

Try with flexbox. Create a wrapper div (In this case `body` element) and use the following CSS.

```
body{
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
}
```

**Note:** With this approach, You don't need `inline-block` property on `.inline-div` elements.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    body {
      display: flex;
      justify-content:center;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="inline-div">
    <p align="center">Input:</p>
    <textarea id="display_new_language"></textarea>
  </div>
  <div class="inline-div">
    <p align="center">Information:</p>
    <textarea id="display"></textarea>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Like I mentioned, you can create a wrapper div around your `.inline-div` (in case you don't want to directly set the `flex` property on body).

**HTML:**

```
<main class="flexWrapper">
  <div class="inline-div">
    <p align="center">Input:</p>
    <textarea id="display_new_language"></textarea>
  </div>
  <div class="inline-div">
    <p align="center">Information:</p>
    <textarea id="display"></textarea>
  </div>
</main>
```

**CSS:**

```
    .flexWrapper{
      display: flex;
      justify-content:center;
    }
```

Comment: Oh thank you very much! It works for me too but unfortunately we are not allowed to use flexbox in our code. But still, this is some new thing for me to learn!

Comment: U are welcome Yixen Lim :) Whenever U need any other help related to Front End feel free to reach out :-) Wish you all the very best. Remember that Flexbox and CSS-grids (especially CSS-Grids) are essential in today's world of technology. U must learn these with time to become a better developer